# how do you make keydown like button sender

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.A)
            {
                foreach (var labels in lblcollection)
                {
                    if (labels.BackColor == Color.Blue)
                    {
                        if (item.Text == "A")
                        {
                            timer2.Start();
                            addbullet();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

How do I make this repeat to all letters in keyboard without doing that manually? Is there a shortcut? Something like:

" button(sender) "

Answer (score 0):

Writing it for each and every key is pretty much the way you have to do it. There is no pre-existing shortcut System in Windows Forms*. e.KeyData is the Sender for this operation, execpt it does not even need casting.

*Well, there is one. But it only applies to [Keyboard-only Navigation of the menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menuitem.shortcut). So propably not the droid you are looking for.

You could structure this up a bit using switch/case blocks. Keys is a enumeration, so you could even use that without the new Pattern Matching support

You can usually repalce a switch/case using a Collection. `Dictionary<Keys, Action>` comes to mind. Using that and Lambda functions you could keep this mostly out of sight.

However Hotkeys also cross over into the Command Pattern, if you plan to use any here. The idea with the pattern is that you have a bunch of commands and several ways (Hotkeys, Buttons, MenuItems) to call them.